# Role based custom authentication system in ASP.NET MVC directing to Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, form-authentication, custom-authentication

Hi I wrote a **role based custom authentication system** for my ASP.NET MVC Application.

So changes I did like Following

In **Global.asax.cs** File added Following Method

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

}
protected void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(Object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs e)
{
try
{
   if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported == true)
   {
    if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
    {
        try
        {                              
            string username = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;
            string roles = string.Empty;

            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            {
                // user --> Roles Getting from DB using Stored Procdure

                roles = user.RoleName;
            }

            e.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(
              new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(username, "Forms"), roles.Split(';'));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
           throw;
        }
    }
}
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

}

in **Web.Config**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

in **FilterConfig.cs** in **App_Start** Folder

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

in Login Controller method

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    // POST: /Account/Login

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginUserViewModel loginmodel, string returnUrl)
    {
       try
       { 
            UserViewModel userdata=null;

            if (loginmodel.UserName != null & loginmodel.Password != null)
            {
                // Get userData via Stored Procedure



                if (userdata != null)
                {                                                                                     

                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginmodel.UserName, false);
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                        && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Home");
                    }


                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login failed.");
                }

            }   
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login failed.");
            }

            return View(userdata);
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
           throw;
       }
    }
```

**Login.cshtml** page

```
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @* rest of data *@
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                            <button type="submit" >Login</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
```

Finally in **HomeController.cs**

```
    [Authorize(Roles="admin")]
    public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
      //rest of fetching
    }
```

Here everything worked perfectly , but Accidentally I Debuged/Run Dashboard View Page without Sign in ,

Now I'm ending up with following error in `FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate` method in `Global.asax` File,

> object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Now when I'm Starting to debug this project its ending there

Comment: Which line throwing object reference exception inside `FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate`? Seems that a variable trying to assign null reference from other object.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto getting error like following http://i.imgur.com/jJb18Mi.png

Answer (score 0):

your Authorise attribute isn't using your implementation, what you have created you should have really done in  custom AuthoriseAttribue that inherits the AuthorizeAttribute

something like this with your own code getting roles and authentication

```
public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
 .... 
 //your code here 
}
```

and then your ViewModel \ Model should look like this

```
[AuthorizeUserAttribute(Roles="admin")]
public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
  //rest of fetching
}
```

Comment: do I need create new class as `AuthorizeUserAttribute` ?

Comment: yes, you will need to. For any custom filters you will need to add a new class but ensure for any filter you use you end it with Attribute and then have some form of inheritance of its base class

Comment: where should I put that `AuthorizeUserAttribute` class inside any specfic location ?, my `Dashboard` controller method in Home Controller Class

Comment: The way I do it is to have a folder called filters where they are all kept. it helps anyone looking at your code know what should be where

Comment: Actually its bit unclear to me, are you recommending to create new folder call `filters`  then create class call `AuthorizeUserAttribute` inside of it, then put `FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate` method inside `AuthorizeUserAttribute` class not in Global.asax ?

Comment: yes, that is what I am saying that you need to do because at the moment you're not calling your implementation

Comment: But then I'm ending with following error :( `The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context` in following lines --> `if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)` line and `string username = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;` line